# Read from a named pipe in bash and pipe it into a java process

Tags: bash, named-pipes

I have a JAVA-Jar-File which is provided by a third-party-dev.
The File reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT.

I was able to configure the JAR-File to write to a log file instead.

But I also have to rewrite the input-source from STDIN to a named pipe, so I can send commands to the java-pocess via my own application.

I already tried this two things to read from the pipeline (bash):

```
cat < pipeline_name | java -jar external_application.jar
```

This works fine for the first command. After receiving the first input line, the 'cat' terminates and I am not able so send commands afterwards.

My other try:

```
tail -f pipeline_name | java -jar external_application.jar
```

This works fine. All commands are passed to the JAVA-Application.
BUT: If the java-application is terminating, the tail -f will run like before.

I need a solution where reading from the pipe is stopped if the JAVA-Process is terminating.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

use [bash redirection](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) and [heres a cheatsheet](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet/)

```
java -jar external_application.jar < pipeline_name
```

the < means the java process will read it's stdin from pipeline_name

Comment: Now I have the following Problem: The JAVA-Application only starts after receiving the first command from the pipeline and the other Problem is: the output in the terminal where the java-process is running gets filled with tons of ">" chars which uses a lot of CPU usage (before: 2-5% after: 60-200%)

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with the java. Unfortunately I have no idea about javaness.